# Is requesting a service (that has a software part) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We sometimes receive questions for service+software sets.
The latest example was someone asking for a bank with a particular API.

Other examples:

- Asking for a taxi company that has an smartwatch app
- Asking for a wine that comes with an aging calculator
- Asking for a browser that pays you money to view advertisements

Are such question on-topic?
If there are grey areas, what are they and where to draw the line in these areas?

Answer (score 3):

Such questions are **off-topic**.

The software must be available to anyone, without:

- Requiring any purchase of non-software goods.
- Requiring any purchase of services.
- Requiring agreeing to any contract that goes beyond the use of the software itself.

Three exceptions:

- Media or license fee for the software. *Example: One-time fee to use WinRAR.*
- Support subscription for the software. *Example: Mandatory yearly support service needed to use Liferay Enterprise.*
- Conditions that are explicitly stated in the question. *Example: If the question asks for an app to monitor my ZeBank account, you can safely assume in your answer that the asker has a ZeBank account, so you are allowed to suggest software that is exclusively available to ZeBank customers.*

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Nicolas wrote in his answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2628/185): SR is about recommending ***software***, not *services*. So in short:

- Asking **for a software** (application, library) to *access* a given service: On-Topic.
- Asking **for a service** that offers some API to be accessed: Off-Topic.

Examples:

- Java library to communicate with "SpecificTaxiService": On-Topic
- Android/iOS app to use with "SpecificTaxiService": On-Topic
- Some taxi service offering a Java library to communicate with it: Off-Topic
- Some taxi service where there's an Android/iOS app (or Windows/Linux/... application) to communicate with it: Off-Topic